# Plot a cell array with double values in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array with time stamp values like (04/12/2015, 09:14:47), I would like to plot this with an array of double numbers (0.0055), how can I do this with matlab?

Thanks!

Kind regards

Aileen

Comment: Thank you! It's working now. :)

Comment: you are welcome & welcome to stackoverflow :)

Comment: @GameOfThrows answer this!

Comment: @AnderBiguri but he already found the answer and it is also a duplicate...

Comment: @GameOfThrows then close as dupe! but lets no leave open unaswered questions in SO